# Problem 5.3 Character theory of finite groups (M. Isaacs)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, characters

Let G be a finite group. Let $H\subseteq G$ be a subgroup of G and suppose $\varphi$ is a class function of $H$ and $\psi$ is a class function of $G$. Show that $(\varphi\psi_H)^G=\varphi^G\psi$.

This problem will be used frequently throughout the book, so it would be very nice to figure it out, but I can't prove it.

I tried to prove in this way:

The character $(\varphi\psi_H)^G$ is afforded to $(V\otimes W_H)^G$ and the character $\varphi^G\psi$ to $(V^G\otimes W)$.
It remains to prove that $(V^G\otimes W)$ and $(V\otimes W_H)^G$ are isomorphic as G-modules, but I have no idea how to do it. In particular, it doesn't come in my mind which homomorphism I should use.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Notice that not every class function is the character of a representation! For starters, a character sends the identity element to a positive integer, but a class function may not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that given a class function $f$ of $H$, the induced class function $f^G$ is defined as $g \mapsto \sum_{s\in S} f_0(s^{-1}gs)$, where $S$ is a set of representatives for the cosets in $G/H$, and $f_0(h)=f(h)$ if $h\in H$ and $0$ otherwise.

Now applying this to $\phi \psi_H$, we get $g \mapsto \sum_{s\in S} \varphi_0(s^{-1}gs)(\psi_H)_0(s^{-1}gs)$. Notice that
$\varphi_0(s^{-1}gs)(\psi_H)_0(s^{-1}gs)=\varphi_0(s^{-1}gs)\psi_H(s^{-1}gs)$ (just check the cases $s^{-1}gs\in H$ or $\not \in H$). In turn, $\psi_H(s^{-1}gs)=\psi(s^{-1}gs)$, and since $\psi$ is a class function for $G$, this equals $\psi(g)$. It follows that you can factor out $\psi(g)$ on the right, so you get $(\varphi \psi)^G=\varphi^G\psi$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 
If, on the other hand, by hypothesis $\varphi$ and $\psi$ are characters, how would the proof change?
Could the first part of the resolution I have proposed be right?

Comment: It would work, and you could see the isomorphism as follows: you have $V$ affording $\phi$ (for $H$) and $W$ affording $\psi$ (for $G$). So now you want to see that $(\mathbb{C}G\otimes_{\mathbb{C}H}V)\otimes W \cong \mathbb{C}G\otimes_{\mathbb{C}H}(V\otimes W_{|H})$. Now define a map $f:(g\otimes v) \otimes w \mapsto g\otimes (v\otimes g^{-1}w)$. This should be $(1)$ A map of $\mathbb{C}G$-modules and $(2)$ surjective (hence bijective by dimension counting).

Comment: Try to prove $(1)$, but if you get stuck: note that $g'$ acts as $(g'g\otimes v) \otimes g'w$, then applying $f$ gives $g'g\otimes(v\otimes g^{-1}w)$, which is $g'\cdot (g\otimes (v\otimes g^{-1}w))$.

Comment: It may get a little confusing since we have two kinds of tensors here: $\otimes_\mathbb{C}$ and $\otimes_{\mathbb{C}G}$